# How to scroll particular row horizontally in the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to command on horizontal and Vertical scrolling of UITableView specially particular row and column.

I am new in iPhone dev, Help me to go forward..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` does not have columns, so there is no need to scroll horizontally.

To scroll to a cell:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]
```

Where the indexPath is the position of the row.

I would suggest that you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `UITableView`.

Answer (score -2):

Scrolling to a specific row in UITableView is done by calling the method:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated:]
```

but the regular UITableView does not have columns.

If you are interested in a horizontal tableView, there is an excelent post on how to implement one in [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)